# OUTER APPLY 100% cpu immediate

Tags: sql-server

I have a query white an Outer Apply which is consuming 100% cpu immediately.
Running the 2 separate queries individually gives immediate results.

```
select s1.correlationid, s1.ucc_id, s1.starttime, s2.concurrentcalls
INTO #Con
from ucc_sessionsummary as s1
      OUTER APPLY (select count(distinct correlationid) concurrentcalls from UCC_SessionSummary as s where s1.starttime between s.starttime and s.endtime) as s2
where s1.starttime between @Starttime and @Endtime
```

I have upladed the plan, can somebody help?
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJ6Pud4bL

Table definition:
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to dba.se. Can you add the table definition to the question?

Comment: Can multiple calls with the same `correlationid` be going on simultaneously? If not there are much better ways of determining the number of concurrent sessions

Comment: Cool - see the "Number of concurrent sessions" part of this answer then https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/216060/3690 - the issue with your current code is that it needs to do the correlated aggregation query repeatedly for every row in the outer query